# Preloading Entry tkinter with Date

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a program, that users enter information in which the data is then outputted into a CSV once clicked generate.

The info that needs to be entered is: Date, Time, Test Station, Serial Number, and then 3 radio button selections.

Currently, i have it so i can enter the date, time, and serial number. But i want the application to automatically update the date and time so that users don't have to enter it. I have imported a date module but no idea how to get it working within the text box.

```html
from tkinter import *

from datetime import date
today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%y")

def save_info():
    date_info = date.get()
    time_info = time.get()
            
    serialNumber_info = serialNumber.get()
    serialNumber_info = str(serialNumber_info)
            
    print(date_info, time_info, serialNumber_info)

    file = open("test.csv", "a")
    file.write(date_info)
    file.write(",")
    file.write(time_info)
    file.write(",")
    file.write(serialNumber_info)
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    print(" User ", date_info, " Has been registered")

    date_entry.delete(0, END)
    time_entry.delete(0, END)
    serialNumber_entry.delete(0, END)

                
screen = Tk()
d1_var = StringVar(screen, d1)
screen.geometry("500x500")
screen.title("Python Form")
heading = Label(text = "Python Form", bg = "grey", fg = "black", width = "500", height = "3")
heading.pack()

date_text = Label(text = "Enter Date '(13/12/2022)' ",)
time_text = Label(text = "Enter Time '(16:45)'",)
serialNumber_text = Label(text = "Enter Serial Number ",)
date_text.place(x = 15, y = 70)
time_text.place(x = 210, y = 70)
serialNumber_text.place(x = 15, y = 210)

date = StringVar()
time = StringVar()
serialNumber = IntVar()

date_entry = Entry(textvariable = d1_var, width = "30")
time_entry = Entry(textvariable = time, width = "30")
serialNumber_entry = Entry(textvariable = serialNumber, width = "30")

date_entry.place(x = 15, y = 100)
time_entry.place(x = 210, y = 100)
serialNumber_entry.place(x = 15, y = 240)
register = Button(screen,text = "Register", width = "30", height = "2", command = save_info, bg = "grey")
register.place(x = 15, y = 400)
```

Comment: you are using d1_var as text variable, but at the end you try to get the date from the date variable which is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the text variable you define to your Entry widget should be a tkinter StringVar. You can define it after creating the Tk() and set any value you want.

```
screen = Tk()
d1_var = StringVar(screen, d1)
```

Then just change the Entry textvariable to `d1_var` instead:

```
date_entry = Entry(textvariable = d1_var, width = "30")
```

Comment: you can also use d1_var.set(value) to change its value later, and d1_var.get() to retrieve its value as a string

Comment: Okay, yeah it worked for what i asked, Thanks. but what i will do now is edit the code to what im using it for. The form will be appended to an existing CSV file, with your edit, it does not append to the CSV.

Comment: i have added the edit

Comment: You should not change your question after finding the answer you needed, because now the answer doesn't make sense for future references. Instead you should add another question.